# Migrating from 2.2 .Net core to 3.0 Cors error

Tags: asp.net-core, migration, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

When Migrating API from 2.2 .NET Core to 3.0 i am facing error with the below code when running the API.

public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)

{

app.UseCors(builder => builder

```
                  .WithOrigins(ConfigurationSettings.CORSAllowedSites)
                  .AllowAnyMethod()
                  .AllowAnyOrigin()
                  .AllowAnyHeader()
                  .AllowCredentials()
                  );
```

}

**Error:The CORS Protocol does not allow specifying a wildcard origin and credentials at the same time.
Configure Cors policy by listing individual origins if credentials need to be supported **

Answer (score 2):

Remove `.AllowCredentials()` from the `app.UseCors` method, like this:

```
  app.UseCors(builder => builder
                      .WithOrigins(ConfigurationSettings.CORSAllowedSites)
                      .AllowAnyMethod()
                      .AllowAnyOrigin()
                      .AllowAnyHeader()
                      );
```